# Understand variable assigment in JS

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am not able to understand this line of code in a highcharts example

```
var chrt = !this.chart ? this : this.chart;
```

Coming from this page
http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/supgh9c1/4/

Can anyone provide a brief description of what it does?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: unwinds to `var chrt = this.chart || this;`

Answer (score 3):

This is a ternary operator or simpler an `if-else` in one line. The same is:

```
var chrt = '';
if(!this.chart){
   chrt  = this
}
else{
    chrt = this.chart
}
```